# What rules govern the Windows 8 store appId? Are they persistent across versions/renames?

Tags: windows-8, winjs, windows-store-apps

[The MSDN page for CurrentApp.appId is here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.appid)

In a typical application the property comes back in the format `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`, and precisely that number if you're running an app that is not in the Windows store.

Once in the Windows store, it gets a real number, and my question is: **Is there anything that would cause an appId to ever change?** Perhaps as versions of the app are updated, or if the app is renamed?

Comment: How would this change affect you?

Comment: License checking, especially if something is licensed per version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AppId will not change unless you remove the existing app and republish.

I do not have a source for this, but it is the same process from the Windows Phone Marketplace/Store. The ID is used in many places.

- The direct link (URL) to your app
- Used by the Store app to identify which apps have an update
- Used by Visual Studio when creating/uploading packages
- ...

Changing the Global Unique Identifier is totally against the point of a GUID. If it changed, many things would break. The ID does not change when updating the app, it remains the same.

Comment: Any source about this statement?